# user provider for api and main firewall with different property

Tags: symfony, security, firewall

I have 2 firewalls, one main one for the web/front end of the application. One for the api. They share a user entity, but i want the provider to load users based on a different property for each firewall.

For the main firewall users can log in with email only.
For the api firewall users can log in with username only.

Here is my setup so far.
My user provider with username as property:

```
app_user_provider:
    entity:
        class: App\Entity\User
        property: userName
```

my firewall:

```
api:
    pattern: ^/api
    stateless: true
    provider: app_user_provider
    custom_authenticators:
        - App\Security\AppLoginAuthenticator
        - App\Security\AppKeyAuthenticator
main:
    lazy: true
    provider: app_user_provider
    custom_authenticators:
        - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
    form_login:
        login_path: app_login
        check_path: app_login
    entry_point: form_login
    logout:
        path: app_logout
```

Comment: Why not define different providers, even if they use the same entity?

Comment: i tried that, but i cant seem to get that configured right.  my userProvider could not load the user correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 providers with same entity and different property:

```
app_user_provider:
    entity:
        class: App\Entity\User
        property: email
api_user_provider:
    entity:
        class: App\Entity\User
        property: userName
```

Autowire your custom authenticator to use the correct one:

```
App\Security\AppLoginAuthenticator:
    arguments:
        $userProvider: "@security.user.provider.concrete.api_user_provider"
```